# Why do I get this "undefined method" error in a Rails model callback, passing the method as a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class called "Post" that should convert its markdown content to HTML when it is changed or it hasn't been converted yet. I'm trying to use the before_save callback with the `if:` argument, but I get this error on whatever I pass to the `if` when I try to run my tests:

> Testing started at 1:55 ... rake aborted!
>   undefined method 'markdown_changed_or_html_nil?' for `#<Post:0x000000053603d0>`
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/jw/app/models/post.rb:7:in `<class:Post>`
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/jw/app/models/post.rb:1:in `<top (required)>`
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/jw/test/test_helper.rb:12:in `<class:TestCase>`
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/jw/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>`
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/jw/test/models/post_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>`
>   -e:1:in 'load'
>   -e:1:in '' Tasks: TOP => test:run => test:units (See full trace by running task with --trace) Run options: --seed 13458
>
> # Running tests:
>
> Finished tests in 0.002000s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
>
> 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

This is the model in question:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  before_save :convert_markdown, if: :markdown_changed_or_html_nil?

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, :title, :content_markdown, { presence: true, on: create }
  validates_associated :user

  protected
    def convert_markdown
      markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, space_after_headers: true, underline: true)
      self.content_html = markdown.render(content_markdown)
    end

    def markdown_changed_or_html_nil?
      content_markdown.changed? || content_markdown.nil?
    end
end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.2.

I might well have made a really really basic mistake - I'm still learning Rails.

---

Edit: this is post_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'saving an empty object fails' do
    new_post = Post.new

    assert_not new_post.save
  end

  test 'validates that given user id corresponds to user' do
    # This will create a user with a given id so we can use the next one up
    test_user = User.create({ name: 'Johnny Test', email: 'johnny.test@example.com',
                            password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password' })

    # Use next id up - there's no reason it should be taken at this point
    given_user_id = test_user.id + 1

    post_with_invalid_user = Post.new({ title: 'Look at my glorious title', content_markdown: 'Sick content',
                                      user_id: given_user_id })

    assert_not post_with_invalid_user.save
  end

  test 'converts markdown into html' do
    # This is a really really basic test just to make sure a conversion happens
    new_post = Post.new({ title: 'Check out this markdown, baby', content_markdown: 'I got some *sick* markdown',
                        user_id: users(:paul).id })

    assert_equal '<p>I got some <em>sick</em> markdown</p>', new_post.content_html
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think those methods need to be protected, and they probably shouldn't be: that might be your problem - putting them in protected means they can only be called from an instance of that class.  Do you get the same problem if you remove `protected`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams the callbacks will fire from the instance of the class if used in an actual callback.  So that shouldn't be a problem.  I think it's more likely to be an issue with the test

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried that earlier - I still get the same error.

Comment: @Baloo, would it help if I posted the test? It doesn't seem to be run, but it might be of some use, I guess.

Comment: @JacobWalker It can't hurt if you'd be so kind.  It may be you're calling it as a class method by mistake

Comment: It is pretty much a blind shot, but try typing `spring stop` before you run tests.

Comment: Have you added any helper methods to test_helper?

Comment: I think the error may be very misleading here. Notice the error is showing on line 7. If the code you posted for your Post class is what is really in your source (you didn't remove comments or extra line breaks). Then I would try removing your validations and see if things work for you. Then go from there.

Comment: @CaptChrisD That did it! Thank you! But now the question is... why were the validations causing that problem? And how can I put them back in without breaking it again?

Comment: @CaptChrisD Turns out the validations were the problem - `create` should have been `:create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be your primary issue (since your error message doesn't seem to relate to it), but you're not using `changed?` correctly. `changed?` needs to be called on your model object, optionally prefixed with your attribute name. So your condition method should look like:

```
def markdown_changed_or_html_nil?
  # based on your method name, shouldn't this be:
  # content_markdown_changed? || content_html.nil?
  content_markdown_changed? || content_markdown.nil?
end
```

Find more information about `Dirty` methods at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html.

**ALSO**

I'm pretty sure Rails 4 hasn't moved `Dirty` out of `ActiveRecord::Base`, so you don't need to manually `include ActiveModel::Dirty` in your model.

**ALSO**

This line:

```
validates :user, :title, :content_markdown, { presence: true, on: create }
```

Should be:

```
validates :user, :title, :content_markdown, { presence: true, on: :create }
```

Comment: You are indeed correct about that line - changed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, Benjamin's comment pointed me in the direction of that `:create` symbol as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`validates :user, :title, :content_markdown, { presence: true, on: create }`

should be

`validates :user, :title, :content_markdown, presence: true, on: :create`

I think ruby is just interpreting everything after `validates :user, :title, :content_markdown` as part of the validates function. Why this is, I have to little knowledge of the interpreter to know but ruby has alot of these 'weird' errors. Looking at the linenumbers as CaptChrisD said is always a good start when you encounter them.

Comment: Boom! Got it! That line should have been `validates :user, :title, :content_markdown, presence: true, on: :create` - `create` should have been a symbol. Thank you :)